# Failure to apply the law of conservation of energy in rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, conservation-laws, rotational-kinematics

I need to calculate the distance $s$, traveled by the body whose mass is $m=0.3kg$, after it has been hit by a rectangle shaped object whose mass is $M=1kg$ and length $l=1m$, which can freely rotate around an axis through $O$, if the coefficient of friction is $\mu=0.2$. The rectangle shaped object stops after hitting the object $m$.

[image]

Now, I know how to apply the law of conservation of angular momentum, but what I'm having trouble understanding is this:

Let point (A) be the point where the rectangular object is at it's highest (before being let down to rotate).

Let point B be the point after the rectangle hits the box.

$E_A = E_B$

$$Mgl = Mg\frac{l}{2} + \frac{mv^2}{2}$$

Where $v$ is the velocity of the object $m$.

Can anyone explain why my equation is not correct? Our workbook  solution is as follows:

$$Mgl = Mg\frac{l}{2} + \frac{I\omega^2}{2}$$

Basically, they chose point B to be the point right before the rectangle hits the box, and thus $$\frac{I\omega^2}{2}$$ is the kinetic energy of rotation of the rectangle.

When I look at it, we just chose different moments to calculate the energy in. Why is my approach wrong?

Comment: Unless you fine tune your parameters, the rotating arm will still have angular velocity after the collision. You are missing the corresponding kinetic energy from this rotation. Your formula is an underestimation.